# Table and ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I would like to do a ListPlot3D of an empirical function where variables c and d are my x and y axes and tkappa is my z.

I either get an empty plot or axis ranges that do not correspond to values of c, d or tkappa.

If I use the code below; I get an empty plot but the axis ranges are correct.

```
tkappa[a_,b_,c_,d_]:= 0.67 - 0.07*a - 0.17*b + 0.40*c + 0.32*d + 0.16*a*b + 0.13*a*c-8.093*10^-4*a*d + 0.13*b*c + 0.084*b*d + 0.27*c*d - 0.10*a*b*c + 0.016*a*b*d+0.051*a*c*d + 0.16*b*c*d -0.059*a*b*c*d;
timingData = Table[{c,d,tkappa[0,0,c,d]},{c,0,1,0.1},{d,0,1,0.1}]
ListPlot3D[timingData]
```

If I use a Table function as an argument for ListPlot3D, I get a surface but the axis ranges don't seem to correspond to c, d or values for tkappa.

```
ListPlot3D[Table[tkappa[0,0,c,d],{c,0,1,0.1},{d,0,1,0.1}]]
```

What is the best approach for ListPlot3D for x,y,z plots?

Comment: You want `ListPlot3D[Flatten[timingData,1]]`.. Look the usage of `ListPlot3D` up. It expects a 1d list of 3d points.

Comment: closely related: [**66078**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66078/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data feed to `ListPlot3D` should be of the form `{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},....}`

```
 timingData = Partition[
              Flatten[Table[{c, d, tkappa[0, 0, c, d]}, {c, 0, 1, 0.1}, {d, 0, 1,0.1}]],
              3];


 ListPlot3D[timingData]
```

[image]