# How do I store x,y,z co-ordinates in a table of 3 dimensions instead of 4?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to store the Cartesian co-ordinates of volume elements inside a finite volume box,

```
posn = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, x1 = -5, x2 = 5, d = .5}, {j, y1 = -5, 
y2 = 5, d = .5}, {k, z1 = -5, z2 = 5, d = .5}];
```

I expect it to give me a three dimensional array, but on checking its dimensions, following output is obtained:

```
Dimensions[posn]
{21, 21, 21, 3}
```

How do I store the values in 3-dimensional array instead?

Comment: But what would those dimensions correspond to? Now first three are about `i j k` and the deepest one is `{i,j,k}` itself. If you want just a 2D array `n x 3` you can use `Flatten]` like in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140856/5478

Comment: You mean to say, the first 3 dimensions store the xyz values and the last one stores the lists {x,y,z}? So, does this mean it is inevitable that such a table will be stored in a 4-D array?

Comment: Unless I missed something I think you are confusing `posn` dimensions with the length of the vector you have at the deepest level.

Comment: The result is a 21 * 21 * 21 array of 3 numbers, the x, y, and z coordinates.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `x1=`, `x2=`, `d=`, etc. parts in the `Table`.

Comment: As a side note, you might be interested in [`CoordinateBoundsArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundsArray.html)

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of ways to skin the cat. You can fully Flatten[ ] and then re-Partition[ ] like this...

```
    posn = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, x1 = -5, x2 = 5, d = .5}, 
                 {j, y1 = -5, y2 = 5, d = .5}, {k, z1 = -5, z2 = 5, d = .5}];

    dposn = Partition[Flatten[posn], 3];
    Dimensions[dposn]
```

$$\{9261,3\}$$

Comment: Just `Flatten` to level `2` to avoid the need to `Partition`: `Flatten[posn, 2]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, yeah, insert mathematician joke about "reducing to known problem" in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
posn = Table[
  ToString[{i, j, k}], {i, x1 = -5, x2 = 5, d = .5}, {j, y1 = -5, 
   y2 = 5, d = .5}, {k, z1 = -5, z2 = 5, 
   d = .5}](*store*)
Dimensions@posn
ToExpression@Part[posn, 1, 1, 1] (*access*)
```

Out:

```
{21, 21, 21}
{-5., -5., -5.}
```