# Improper formatting for input to ListPlot3D, backwards incompatibility on 12.1?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

For context, I am a brand new user to Mathematica using version 12.1 on Linux.

I'm looking at an [old notebook (2011)](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/mathematica_src/burgers_characteristics/burgers_characteristics.html) that looks at the inviscid burger's equation.

The relevant bits from the notebook are as follows:

```
(* Initial condition *)
f0[x_] := Exp [ - ( 2 * ( x - 1 ) )^2 ];
x[t_, x0_] := x0 + f0[x0] * t;
f[t_, x0_] := f0[x0];

ListPlot3D [ {Table[
   Table[{x[t, x0], t, f[t, x0]}, {x0, -0.5, 3.0, 0.1}], {t, 0, 2, 
    0.1}]},
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.9]],
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
 AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["<--X-->", Italic, 23]], 
   Text[Style["<--T-->", Italic, 23]],
   Text[Style["U(X,T)", Italic, 23]]}]
```

The desired solution is shown below:

[image: Proper Solution]

Instead, I get an error:

```
ListPlot3D::arrayerr: {{<<1>>}} must be a valid array or a list of valid arrays.
```

Following another [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66078/table-for-3d-list-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1), I tried to use `Flatten` to resolve the error:

```
testC = Flatten[
   Table[{x[t, x0], t, f[t, x0]}, {x0, -.5, 3, .1}, {t, 0.0, 2, 0.1}],
    1];

ListPlot3D[testC,
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> {True, True, True},
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

The error got resolved, but the plot is wrong/degenerates:

[image: Spiky Burgers Surface Plot]

Using `ListPointPlot3D` instead, however, shows the right shape:

[image: Correct Scatter of Points]

What's wrong with the formatting for the `ListPlot3D` input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to kglr's answer but without the use of splines.

Since the plot folds over, there are portions of the plot for which there is not a unique `z` for an `{x, y}`. [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) is able to handle such cases.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(*Initial condition*)
f0[x_] := Exp[-(2*(x - 1))^2];
x[t_, x0_] := x0 + f0[x0]*t;
f[t_, x0_] := f0[x0];

ParametricPlot3D[{x[t, x0], t, f[t, x0]}, {t, 0, 2}, {x0, -1/2, 3},
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.9],
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 Boxed -> False,
 ImageSize -> 600,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Italic, 23] & /@ {"<--X-->", "<--T-->", "U(X,T)"}),
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bob-hanlon. This works! Any idea when `ListPlot3D` stopped working for this type of plot? Presumably, the initial code worked in 2011.

Comment: I do not know. The documentation for `ListPlot3D` shows "Introduced in 1988 (1.0) | Updated in 2007 (6.0) * 2010 (8.0) * 2012 (9.0) * 2014 (10.0) * 2016 (11.0) * 2017 (11.1) * 2019 (12.0) * 2020 (12.1)"

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) and [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html):

```
bsF = BSplineFunction @ 
   Table[{x[t, x0], t, f[t, x0]}, {x0, -0.5, 3.0, 0.1}, {t, 0, 2, 0.1}];

ParametricPlot3D[bsF[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.9]],
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["<--X-->", Italic, 23], 
   Style["<--T-->", Italic, 23], Style["U(X,T)", Italic, 23]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kglr. This works, but Bob Hanlon's answer is slightly simpler.